# How to find maintenability rating from sonarqube api for the leak period

Tags: api, sonarqube, rating

I would like to get maintenability rating for a project during the leak period from sonarqube api.

I have found easily the url to get maintenability rating but not just for the leak period (SONAR_URL/api/measures/component?metricKeys=sqale_rating&component=PROJECT_KEY).

For security rating and reliavility rating, we need to add as prefix 'new_' to the metrics key for find directly. I would like to find something in the same way if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to sqale_rating in leak period seems to be new_maintainability_rating.

you can check it on you own server by watching the ouput of API url :
http://{your sonar server url}/api/measures/component?component={one of your project}&metricKeys=sqale_rating,new_maintainability_rating&additionalFields=metrics,periods